# OnPause called after OnResume after calling recreate

Tags: java, android, onpause, recreate

I have app with 3 activities.

1. Main Activity A
2. Side Activity B
3. Side Activity C

From Main Activity I can go directly to B and C as well. All moves looks like that:

A->B->C

A->C

A->B

Ofc when I want go back when I'm in C I need to know that I came from A or B and then back to proper one. And that casues me some trobule.

When I go to C acitivity through B, and then back to B `onPause` is called twice. The point is that when I back like that I need to call `recreate` (language change)

In C I have variable which tells me that I go from A or B.

Code in C

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.back_button) {
        if(from_B)
           {
               onBackPressed();
           }
        else
           {
               goes_to_A();
            }
}
```

Code B

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(from_B)
        {from_B = false;
            recreate();}
```

So when I go back to B like that lifecycle looks like: `OnResume` -> then I call `recreate();` -> `onPause` -> `onCreate` -> `onResume` -> `onPause`!  and that last onPause is strange because app should normally work after last onResume. It gives me later errors like

```
Performing pause of activity that is not resumed
```

what's wrong with that ?

Comment: this is because you are calling recreate from onResume. Use some kind of delay to call it.